# Automatically count the modification (for instance added/deleted letters) along a whole git branch

Tags: git, diff, git-commit

Is there a way (or a hack or a script) that can be used to count the number of letters added (or deleted) in every commit of a git branch? Any idea on how to do that?

I know how to use `git diff` just between two commits. Is there an instruction that solves the issue?

**Other Informations: why may I want this feature?**

The goal, for me, should be to plot the evolution of work using some figures of merits. I know this figure of merit is absolutely far away from being a good metric. However, it is still interesting to have this data and use them in the way you prefer (plotting the evolution using python is just an example).

**An idea on how to perform it**:

- to perform a `git diff` of all consecutive commits in a branch.
- to count, for every output of the previous point, the number of letters (making a distinction between deleted and added).
- to save the data in some variable and use the result in the way you prefer the most.

> I will try to implement the procedure with a script and share the
>   solution in this question. However, I am wondering if there are some
>   other direct methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I promised, I did a python script that does the dirty job. It can be found in this [git repo](https://github.com/leos313/python_git_analysis). The result will look like this:

[image]

Basically, I have found a python library that works quite good with git. More information on this [link](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html). The name of the library is **GitPython** and is a nice open-source project.

The strategy is easy and was explained within the question. In order to use the library, after the installation (I used `conda`), you need just to import:

```
from git import Repo
```

Later, in the code, you can use all the API that you can find in the link above. Feel free to re-use the script citing the work.

> Moreover, if you want to contribute by adding functionalities, please
>   do it: I will be glad to test new solutions. For instance, a
>   minimalistic GUI or the managing or multiple branches can be future
>   ideas to be implemented.